# Synchronization in Robotium

Tags: android, testing, robotium

How long does [robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/) wait for a new activity to show up? Is it possible to set the timeout manually for the Solo instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you want that timeout for?

If you want to wait for the new activity to show up, you can use:

```
getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
```

But since you are using [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/) I guess they already do that for you.

Comment: Well, if the product code freezes, ideally, I didn't want the test code to freeze as well. It would be interesting for the test code to throw an exception if it cannot synchronize after a while.

Comment: Oh, now I get what you are saying. I would create an issue on http://code.google.com/p/robotium/issues/list and see what the robotium's guys answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you not specify timeout manually, method `solo.waitForActivity()` will have default timeout **10 seconds**. Because Robotium is open source project you can look it yourself by opening source code / class Waiter.